# What do you call a syllable that makes a snake-like sound?

Tags: word-request

I am thinking there's a word or an adjective for syllables that makes snake-like sounds, I don't know if a syllable that contain the letter s qualifies, or if it restricted to a very few syllables, but I think there's a word for it, but I don't remember what it was.

For example:

> The poem had a lot of ___ syllables.

Comment: Are you perhaps thinking of *sibilant*? It designates phones, not syllables.

Comment: May be *hissing*?

Comment: @StoneyB: "phones" or "phonemes"?

Comment: @virolino Phones. I can make all sorts of sibilant sounds which are non-phonemic.

Comment: @StoneyB: I was not aware of this meaning of the word "phone". I will have to study a bit more about it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you think of consonants, not syllables.

It can be [Voiceless alveolar fricative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_alveolar_fricative) or [Voiceless dental non-sibilant fricative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_dental_non-sibilant_fricative).

Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fricative_consonant).

If you have another sound in mind, it can be called differently.

Answer (score 0):

As StoneyB pointed out in the comments, the sound that is characterised by a hissing effect is called a '**sibilant**'. S, Z, SH, ZH sounds in English are often referred to as 'sibilants'.

'Voiceless alveolar fricative' is the /s/ sound and is a sibilant as Virolino's answer suggests. However, 'voiceless dental non-sibilant fricative' is the TH sound as in 'thin' which isn't a sibilant.